# Package nuxt app in different environment

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I would like to run `npm run generate` with environment

for example:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "staging": "NODE_ENV=staging nuxt generate"
}
```

Generate a `dist/` with staging environment using

```
npm run staging
```

then when requesting to an API I would like to determine what URL I'm going to use depends on the the environment I'm running

```
let baseURL = () => {
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case "it":
      return "https://example-url.com/it";
    case "staging":
      return "https://example-url.com/staging";
  }
};

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL(),
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Api-Key": state().token
  }
});
```

the `baseURL()` should return the staging since I packaged the app in staging env

Comment: so what the problem with your code?  Keep in mind that env variables are set build time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deploying my app to s3. I would like to deploy the code with environment attached so that the app knows which URL to call. I managed to do this by adding this in **package.json**

```
    "generate": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=it nuxt generate",
```

According to this https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/#automatic-injection-of-environment-variables

Comment: Works for "npm run build" and "npm run start" as well.